# Change multiple columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner in Python and made my first venture into Pandas today. What I want to do is to convert several columns from string to float. Here's a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def convert(str):
    try:
        return float(str.replace(',', ''))
    except:
        return None

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', '1,234', '456,789'],
    ['B', '1'    , '---'    ]
], columns=['Company Name', 'X', 'Y'])
```

I want to convert `X` and `Y` to float. The reality has more columns and I don't always know the column names for `X` and `Y` so I must use integer indexing.

This works:

```
df.iloc[:, 1] = df.iloc[:, 1].apply(convert)
df.iloc[:, 2] = df.iloc[:, 2].apply(convert)
```

This doesn't:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:2] = df.iloc[:, 1:2].apply(convert)
# Error: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (2,1)
```

Is there anyway to apply the `convert` function on multiple columns at once?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `astype`?

Comment: How are you reading the data? Using read_csv with parameter thousands=',' might do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your logic:

1. The slice `1:2` *excludes* `2`, consistent with list slicing or `slice` object syntax. Use `1:3` instead.
2. Applying an element-wise function to a series via [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) works. To apply an element-wise function to a dataframe, you need [`pd.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html).
3. *Never* shadow built-ins: use `mystr` or `x` instead of `str` as a variable or argument name.
4. When you use a `try` / `except` construct, you should generally specify error type(s), in this case `ValueError`.

Therefore, this is one solution:

```
def convert(x):
    try:
        return float(x.replace(',', ''))
    except ValueError:
        return None

df.iloc[:, 1:3] = df.iloc[:, 1:3].applymap(convert)

print(df)

  Company Name     X       Y
0            A  1234  456789
1            B     1     NaN
```

However, your logic is inefficient: you should look to leverage column-wise operations wherever possible. This can be achieved via [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), along with [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) applied to each *series*:

```
def convert_series(x):
    return pd.to_numeric(x.str.replace(',', ''), errors='coerce')

df.iloc[:, 1:3] = df.iloc[:, 1:3].apply(convert_series)

print(df)

  Company Name     X       Y
0            A  1234  456789
1            B     1     NaN
```

Comment: Slow, though? Using `applymap` and dealing with errors that way? You'll still end up with mixed types?

Comment: @roganjosh, Yeh I've added the recommended series-wise solution. The end products here are identical because (apparently) Pandas does recast to `float` after `applymap`. I wouldn't rely on this, though, and that's yet another reason to use series-wise methods.

Comment: Python and Pandas are entirely new to me. Thanks for your help

Comment: @MikeHenderson, No problem, most of my points are generic to Python (not just Pandas-related), so hopefully it will help you elsewhere.